# Unable to login Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, login

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`. Laptop was working normally, I did a restart and since then I cannot login. I get to the login screen, enter password, and then this message appears for a second and login page reappears.

```
speed-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speed-dispatcher
saned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
Restoring resolver state
```

I can access `TTY` and have tried the following commands:

1.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

2.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

3.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

When the laptop was working I did `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`, edited and saved the file, closed the text editor and immediately pressed <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in the terminal (didn't wait for the process to automatically terminate in the terminal). I'm not sure but this might be related to the login issue.

**EDIT:** `/etc/environment/` originally contained the environment variables I defined, `FOO="BAR"`. I had changed them to `export FOO="BAR"`. Changed just a few, not all. But have reverted the changes after logging to `TTY`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the content of your edited /etc/environment file.

Comment: @user535733 Added the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following line to `.profile`,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

Reference: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2267058&p=13236758#post13236758